# Qualtrics randomization within each field in loop and merge

Tags: qualtrics

I have 3 different fields with be shown images defined (urls from the library) in the loop & merge in Qualtrics. I have 3 different questions and each question will show an image (together with a question underneath) selected from each of the field.

How can I get Qualtrics to draw images randomly from each field? For example, currently, if it shows row 1 from field 1 for questions 1, it also shows row 1 from field 2 and 3 for question 2 and 3 respectively. I want to make these row selections from each field random. Is there a java script or some way around in Qualtrics settings to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Each row is a loop, and you can't access loop & merge fields from another loop (row).

You need to randomize the image urls and store them in embedded data fields prior to the loop & merge.  Then pipe them into the loop & merge fields.